# Spring Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW @Transaction commit appears in log only after outter transaction end

Tags: transactions, transactionscope, spring-transactions

I have a transactional methods invoking each other but it seems that transaction commits after the spot it should commit or at least insertion logs appear after that. Here is the call hierachy:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public DataProcessingStatistics copyInitialRevision() {
    try {
        DataProcessingStatistics statistics = new DataProcessingStatistics();
        transaction(statistics);
        statistics.printResult();
        return statistics;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)  
public void transaction(DataProcessingStatistics statistics) {
    entityAuditTableService.generateTables(statistics);
    oneToManyRelationAuditTableService.generateTables(statistics);
    manyToManyRelationAuditTableService.generateTables(statistics);
}

...

 @Service
 public class EntityAuditTableServiceImpl implements EntityAuditTableService {
...

@Override
public void generateTables(DataProcessingStatistics statistics) {
    List<EntityAuditTable> auditTables = loadAll();
    for (EntityAuditTable auditTable : auditTables) {
        try {
            statistics.addAsProcessed(auditTable, process(auditTable));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            statistics.addAsSkipped(auditTable.getAuditTable(), e);             
        }
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public int process(EntityAuditTable auditTable) {
    EntityDataTable table = entityDataTableService.create(auditTable.getEntityDataTable().getEntityClass());
    List<EntityDataTableRow> rows = entityDataTableService.readAllData(table);
    List<EntityAuditTableRow> auditTableRows = entityAuditTableRowService.generateTableData(auditTable, rows);
    entityAuditTableRowService.saveAll(auditTableRows);
    return auditTableRows.size();
}

...


 @Service
 public class EntityAuditTableRowServiceImpl implements EntityAuditTableRowService {

...


@Override
@Transactional
public void saveAll(List<EntityAuditTableRow> auditTableRows) {
    jdbcService.saveArraysAs500RowChunks(auditTableRows, new ListSaver<EntityAuditTableRow>(){
        @Override
        public void save(List<EntityAuditTableRow> list) {
            EntityAuditTableRowServiceImpl.this.saveJdbc(list);
            for (EntityAuditTableRow auditTableRow: list) {
                entityChangeService.saveFromRow(auditTableRow);
            }
        }
    });
}

...


@Service
public class JdbcServiceImpl implements JdbcService {

@Override
public <E> void saveArraysAs500RowChunks(List<E> rows, ListSaver<E> saver) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i += 500) {
        save500(rows.subList(i, Math.min(i +500, rows.size())), saver);
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public <E> void save500(final List<E> rows, ListSaver<E> saver) {
    if (rows == null || rows.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (rows.size() > 500) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("(auditTableRows.size() > 500)");
    }
    saver.save(rows);
}   

...

@Service
public class EntityChangeServiceImpl implements EntityChangeService {


@Override
@Transactional
public void saveFromRow(EntityAuditTableRow auditTableRow) {
    Revision revision = revisionsService.load(auditTableRow.getAuditTableRow().getRevision().getId());
    EntityChange entityChange = create(auditTableRow);
    save(entityChange);
    revision.getEntitiesChanges().add(entityChange);
    revisionsService.save(revision);
}

...
@Service
public class RevisionServiceImpl implements RevisionService {

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Revision create() {
    Revision revisionEntity = createDetached();
    long generateNextIdForClass = idService.generateNextIdForClass(Revision.class);
    revisionEntity.setId(generateNextIdForClass);
    revisionEntity.setTimestamp(new Date());
    save(revisionEntity);
    return revisionEntity;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(Revision revisionEntity) {
    persistenceManagerHibernate.save(revisionEntity);
}
```

The thing is only after the return from the root/initial method call i receive inserts in logs for ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION table/EntityChange entity:

this point:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public DataProcessingStatistics copyInitialRevision() {
    try {
        DataProcessingStatistics statistics = new DataProcessingStatistics();
        transaction(statistics);
        statistics.printResult();
        return statistics; // only after that return insert log appear
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

this logs appears only after return:

```
Hibernate: insert into ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_NAME, GROUP_ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME, REV_ID, REVISION_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_NAME, GROUP_ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME, REV_ID, REVISION_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_NAME, GROUP_ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME, REV_ID, REVISION_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_NAME, GROUP_ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME, REV_ID, REVISION_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_NAME, GROUP_ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME, REV_ID, REVISION_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_NAME, GROUP_ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME, REV_ID, REVISION_TYPE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Instead of reveiving them after return from "save 500 row chunk" method which is @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW):

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public <E> void save500(final List<E> rows, ListSaver<E> saver) {
    if (rows == null || rows.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (rows.size() > 500) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("(auditTableRows.size() > 500)");
    }
    saver.save(rows); // invokes EntityChangeServiceImpl.saveFromRow
}   

...

@Service
public class EntityChangeServiceImpl implements EntityChangeService {


@Override
@Transactional
public void saveFromRow(EntityAuditTableRow auditTableRow) {
    Revision revision = revisionsService.load(auditTableRow.getAuditTableRow().getRevision().getId());
    EntityChange entityChange = create(auditTableRow);
    save(entityChange);
    revision.getEntitiesChanges().add(entityChange);
    revisionsService.save(revision);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Transactional method of a class invokes other transactional method of this class without proxy, so second method transaction not used in invokation.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the `@Transactional` and thus open it, the execution must be done through a `proxy`.